xampp connection with sftp server
How to connect Xampp PHP 8.1.25 (windows 11) to SFTP server (RHEL9). I have tried to connect using sftp_connect(SFTP_HOST,22) but it is giving error as

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect()


Previously you were getting an error from ssh2_connect: https://stackoverflow.com/q/79257463/850848 – now you cannot even call it. So you must have somehow broken it. And you didn't bother to even tell us.

@MartinPrikryl i tried to update the ssh2 version to resolve my issue. I didnt get what you mean by i broken it?

@SunilPawar Well,look at your current error. Now it's saying ssh2_connect is undefined. This means that your PHP environment now doesn't have the ss2 module loaded at all. So you are in a worse position than before. If you had tried to update something, it seems maybe you messed it up.

I have re-install xampp and tried to connect the sftp without changing any dll files but still facing same error as
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ssh2_connect() in D:\Projects\xampp\htdocs\bse-scan\functions.php:136
